# how to save same tag model for all store views?

Tags: magento-1.9, tags

When trying to save tag model as following (assuming that `$storeId = 0`) :

```
    $tagModel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
    $tagModel->setName($tagName)
        ->setFirstCustomerId($customerId)
        ->setFirstStoreId($storeId)
        ->setStatus($tagModel->getApprovedStatus())
        ->save();
```

It is not visible to all other `store views`, is it possible to `save` on `tag` for `all store views` somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it is not possible because by default for tag you can select only one store at a time there is no multiselect for that.

you can check it on  `catalog > All Tag` click on `Add New Tag` there no option for that. you have to add tag for every store.